# is it correct to say:I am not here to 'give' you calm?

Tags: american-english

i am.not a native speaker , but I am  trying to become a writer. You can keep someone calm, calm someone down, but what about giving someone calm?

Comment: It can certainly be used poetically, even if it's not a normal expression. Just as you could write *she brings calm to the table*, which is both figurative and understandable—even if not something that would typically be expressed in that way. But it would be perfectly fine in some types of writing.

Answer (score 1):

It would certainly be idiomatic to "provide calm" (e.g."to the situation").

It is also idiomatic to "give calm" (e.g. "to the injured after an accident"), but more usual to "provide calm", I would suggest.

This is purely the response of a native speaker, and does not take account of an Ngrams etc.

Comment: Yeah, Ngrammed it and the use of "give calm", where "calm" is a noun, occurs but is exceedingly rare.  Most often you see something like "give calm attention to ..." or simply "...give. Calm ..."  But I can imagine situations where I would use it.